# What do you call a graph where the vertices are signed?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, signed-graphs

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph, and $f: V \to \{1,-1\}$ be a function assigning a sign to each vertex. What is this system $(G, f)$ called?

---

- In my current research, we've been using "oriented graph" to refer to the above structure; each vertex is assigned an *orientation* which is one of "oriented" or "unoriented". But other sources use "oriented graph" to mean a directed graph where there is at most one edge between a given pair of vertices.
- A "signed graph" assigns $\pm 1$ to the edges, but not to the vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might call it a vertex-signed graph.  See e.g. [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1652).